# Keycloak w/Google Authentication - Invalid username or password

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, keycloak, google-signin

I'm trying to configure my local Keycloak 8.0.1 instance to use Google as an identity provider.  I'm following [the instructions I found here](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-signin-to-keycloak-using-google.html).  I've got my Identity Provider, realm, and client configured accordingly.  When I hit the login page I see the button to perform a Google login.  However, when I click it and go through the Google consent page, I'm eventually taken back to Keycloak and see an error saying, `"We are sorry... Invalid username or password."`  In my Keycloak logs I see the following:

```
21:24:26,794 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-25) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1001)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService$1.authenticateOnly(LoginActionsService.java:769)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:860)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:296)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.brokerLoginFlow(LoginActionsService.java:799)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.firstBrokerLoginGet(LoginActionsService.java:694)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:91)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

21:24:26,796 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-25) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_FIRST_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=myrealm, clientId=myrealm-default, userId=null, ipAddress=<MY IP ADDRESS>, error=invalid_user_credentials, identity_provider=google, auth_method=openid-connect, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/myrealm-console/TestServlet, identity_provider_identity=MY_EMAIL@gmail.com, code_id=<UUID>, authSessionParentId=<UUID>, authSessionTabId=<ID>
```

I haven't changed anything except the realm name from the instructions.  Any idea why I would be seeing this error?

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure how it works but I tried this and it worked fine.

Step 1: In Identity Providers check if 'google'(the identity provider for Google login) has "First Login Flow" as first broker login.

Step 2: Goto "Authentication", under, "Flows" select ''first broker login'.

Step 3: For the "Create User If Unique(create unique user config)", select "REQUIRED"

Try logging in again. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Happy that you managed to found it so easily. But why does it has to occur? I mean, I used the same providers in Keycloak 7 and had no problem with them. Is it new ?